# How to read logon time - notification to change seat position

Tags: authentication, time, notifications, popup, counting

I want a small app for myself for work. I have desk with height adjustment so I want to measure logon time and when one hour has passed I need notification for changing body position, in loop. So I need:

- Counting logon time (when computer is on locked screen, time stops.)
- Pop-up notification - or simple GUI

I know basic Java and Python. I hope you can give me some advice. I want to learn, I didn't come here for ready app.

How should I start?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. First, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking this type of question is not a good one to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean, this part with getting processes is poor. it takes a lot of resources of computer. Please take a look.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time

counter = 0

while True:

    # getting process list
    proc = Popen('wmic process', stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    procList = str(proc.communicate()).lower()

    # counter, if time is up, change position.
    if counter == 10:
        counter = 0
        sg.Popup("Move yourself")

    # if process exists, wait 5 seconds, process exists only on lockup screen
    elif 'logonui.exe' in procList:
        time.sleep(5)

    # if it doesnt, wait 2 seconds and count 1.
    else:
        time.sleep(2)
        counter += 1
```

Another soultion using psutil, much faster and feels little bit lighter. But i'm not sure about this list idea. I create list and clean it every time...

```
import time
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import psutil


procList = ''
counter = 0

while True:

    # getting process list
    for proc in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['name']):
        procList += str(proc.info).lower()

    # counter, if time is up, change position.
    if counter == 10:
        counter = 0
        sg.Popup("Move yourself")

    # if process exists, wait 5 seconds
    elif 'logonui.exe' in procList:
        time.sleep(10)
        procList = ''

    # if it doesnt, wait 2 seconds and count 1.
    else:
        time.sleep(5)
        counter += 1
        procList = ''
```

Comment: Why can't you just sleep?  I edited my answer to include this simple solution.  I don't understand the need to do the other stuff in your loop.  Is this program supposed to do a lot of other things?  I thought you needed a single program to do nothing but popup every 2 minutes or so.

Comment: Oh... I think I understand better... you want your timer running only when a specific process is also running?
If so then psutil is an ok way to do it.  I wouldn't check very often.  Given the long amount of time you'll be counting, checking every 30 seconds should be fine.  Otherwise those calls to psutil will eat up too much cpu.   What you've written isn't bad at all if this is what you need.

Comment: Yes, i realized the process logonui.exe running only on lockup screen. So i want to count time when process doesnt exists. That is representation of my real time behind the desk :) Thanks a lot for your time. I set up 30 seconds breaks beetwen checking. Code looks and works fine . Greetings

Comment: Awesome!  Congrats.  I hope the GUI portion was "simple".  Seems like the more difficult part was the determination if you're there.

Answer (score 0):

If your question of "How should I start?" then I would think it's to pick a direction and start.
For this I would choose Python.  You just need a program running that popup a window every now and then.  The GUI is easy, straightforward. For that I would choose [PySimpleGUI](http://www.pysimpleGUI.org).
It's 1-line of Python code to show a popup window.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# do your timer stuff here...
# when time to remind you....
sg.Popup("Get up and move around")
```

I was thinking something SUPER simple... show a message every 2 minutes.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(2*60)            # wait 2 minutes
    sg.Popup('Get up and move around')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for advice. I wrote some solution. It works but i feel it can be done better.